# Aren't the ROS and catkin tutorials mixed?

Tags: ros, catkin, tutorial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been looking at the ROS tutorial page (http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials), and it appears to be mixed with he catkin tutorial page (http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials).

For example, there's twice the tutorial 'Creating a ROS package', and the 'Overlaying with catkin workspaces' is shown at the ROS tutorial page, while that is a very specific catkin tutorial.

I'm unsure whether I can change the page myself, but I feel as if it should be changed. The current setup is confusing for new users.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/82976/aren%27t-the-ros-and-catkin-tutorials-mixed?/) by [RafBerkvens](https://answers.ros.org/users/4316/rafberkvens/) on ROS Answers with karma: 386 on 2013-09-24

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think I fixed what @RafBerkvens is talking about. Basically there were catkin tutorials which were interleaved into the ROS tutorials, but only in the listing. Something like this:

- ROS Tutorial 1
- ROS Tutorial 2
- Catkin Tutorial 1
- ROS Tutorial 3
- Catkin Tutorial 2
- ...

Someone added a fork in the tutorial chain which wasn't natural.

@RafBerkvens, does the new setup help?

Edit:

This change is responsible, it also previously wiped out the later Tutorials, which I caught and fixed at the time, but I missed this subtle change before:

http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/NavigatingTheFilesystem?action=diff&rev1=105&rev2=106

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-09-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RafBerkvens](https://answers.ros.org/users/4316/rafberkvens/) on 2013-09-25**:
Yes, this solves the issue I was reporting. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are probably lots of places in the wiki that are still mixed up. If you find one and know how to correct it, go ahead. Otherwise, asking here is good. In that example, I believe both tutorials point to the same pages.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-09-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RafBerkvens](https://answers.ros.org/users/4316/rafberkvens/) on 2013-09-25**:
Thanks for the reply. I don't believe I'm able to correct it myself.
I don't think they point to the same pages. The catkin tutorial explains some technical details. Plus, the navigation at the button of the page is different, not following the structure on the main ROS tutorials page.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-09-25**:
The ROS creating package page includes the catkin one when the "catkin" button is pressed. What other differences are confusing? Those who have worked with catkin for a while can use help understanding what new users need.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-09-25**:
The ROS workspace overlaying tutorial points directly to the catkin one.